# How to insert a string after substring which contains few words

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I need to add a substring inside other string.

The problem is a need to add this after few given word.

For example:
need to put: $$$

String: 'Give me my money back.'

The result should be : 'Give me my money $$$ back.'

And in case when my string contains like: 'Give me money back.'

The result should be: 'Give me money back.' without any changes

I mean the substring should be insert only when string contains 'my money ' and after him insert new substring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method for adding `$$$`. Also inside [replace method there is special meaning for `$`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), so for inserting single `$` you need to use `$$`.

```js
console.log(
  'Give me my money back.'.replace(/my money/, '$& $$$$$$')
  // or '...'.replace('my money', '$& $$$$$$')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function that will take 3 arguments: the original string, the string you want to match in the original string and the string that will be inserted after the match in your original string. The following code does just that:

```js
var s1 = 'Give me my money back.';
var s2 = 'Give me money back.';
var ss = 'my money';

function addDollars(originalString, matchText, addedText){
  if(originalString.indexOf(matchText) > -1)
    return originalString.slice(0,originalString.indexOf(matchText)+matchText.length)
    +' ' +addedText+originalString.slice(originalString.indexOf(matchText)+matchText.length);
  else
    return originalString;
  }

console.log(addDollars(s1,ss,'$$$'));
console.log(addDollars(s2,ss,'$$$'));
```